# Eclipse demands an extra { }... Why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making an Android app, and I just started working on a piece of code that has to handle the movement of an ImageView in another class file. That's working fine (so far), so that's not what my question is about. This is the code I have:

```
public class BackgroundMovement extends MenuScreen {

    public float heightDp = 0;
    public float widthDp = 0;
    public int isShowing = 0;

    public void onCreate() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        heightDp = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.density;
        widthDp = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density;
    }

    public Random rand = new Random();
    public int leftRight = rand.nextInt(2); [HERE]

    if (isShowing == 0) {

    }
}
```

You've probably noticed the very odd [HERE] in my code. I put that in because that's where Eclipse wants me to add in a {, and naturally, a } at the end.
So my question is: why?
I have no idea whatsoever, and I really want to fix it...

Comment: It's just because you forgot to put the `if` statement inside a method.

Comment: You probably meant to put the `if (isShowing)` inside a method, but putting it in an init block (as Eclipse is suggesting) would satisfy the compiler.  but your code would not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bare control statement outside of any method or init block, at the top level of your class:

```
if (isShowing == 0) {}
```

This isn't valid java syntax, and Eclipse is complaining. But more significantly, the compiler will also complain about that line: as it is, your class won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Should be inside a method

```
if (isShowing == 0) {

}
```

Comment: No need to move `int leftRight = rand.nextInt(2);` inside a method.

Comment: yeah the variable decl at class top-level is fine, so long as `rand` is declared somewhere.